# Display Katalon test results in Xray?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio, jfrog-xray

One of our customers uses Katalon Studio and would like to see the reporting results in Xray and Jira again after the execution of the test cases.

Do I have to create a Json file at the end of the test run? That I have to import into Xray?

Is the Katalon export plugin sufficient here?

Or does the Xray plugin offer me exactly this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of today, AFAIK, Katalon doesn't have yet a specific integration with Xray. You may ask the Katalon team to provide it by submiting them a feature request.
Meanwhile, you can follow these intructions to have visibility of the results in Xray using a JUnit XML report which will autoprovision Test issues.

https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY/Testing+APIs+using+Katalon+Studio

If you would like to enforce a specific test in Katalon to an existing Test issue, you would have to use a different format such as Xray JSON; however, that would require you to build it using some logic based on the information in Katalon.